# Redudant way of saving data in multiple dict, how to solve this?

Tags: python, if-statement

Iam reading a configuration file of a video game, and want to save specific commands and its value in a dict. Example how a command looks like:

> xcommand_name "value of the command"

Also I want to group them in different dict, for exampel: sens_commands = {}, hud_commands = {}

Here is how I implemented it. `command` is the command to check and got split into a list before, so `command[0]` is the command name, and `command[1]` is the value of the command.

```
def get_command(command):
    # check if command name in the viewmodel_command_name and store in the corresponding dict
    if command[0] in viewmodel_command_names:
        viewmodel_commands[command[0]] = command[1]

    if command[0] in crosshair_command_names:
        crosshair_commands[command[0]] = command[1]

    if command[0] in bob_command_names:
        bob_commands[command[0]] = command[1]

    #repeating for other commands
```

The problem is that it looks very very redudant, but I do not know how to solve it. PyCharm also states that it is "Duplicated code fragment", but only gives me this bad solution:

```
    if command[0] not in viewmodel_command_names:
        pass
    else:
        viewmodel_commands[command[0]] = command[1]
```

I tried to find similiar questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to store commands as a dictionary. Then replace your ifs as a for loop:

```
def get_command(command):
    command_dictionary = {
        viewmodel_command_names: viewmodel_commands,
        crosshair_command_names: crosshair_commands,
        bob_command_names: bob_commands
    }
    for command_names, commands in command_dictionary.items():
        if command[0] in command_names:
            commands[command[0]] = command[1]
```